# How to add a new column with Yii 2 migrations on a specific position in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, database-migration

Let's say I have this table structure:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | country | city | address | zipcode | created             | updated             |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Duvdevan   | Duvdevani | NULL    | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | 2016-02-12 15:37:19 | 2016-02-12 16:35:57 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And I want to add a new column called `email`, just after `id` and before `first_name`, using the `addColumn` [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#addColumn%28%29-detail) of the `Migration` class.

Only thing I can do in my new migration is:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn('contacts', 'email', $this->string(64));
}
```

And it will put it at the end of the table, after `updated` field.

How can I add a column at a specific position within my table, so this SQL query could be respected:

```sql
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(64) AFTER id
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved it. If anyone faces the same issue, this is the solution I used:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn('contacts', 'email', 'VARCHAR(64) AFTER id');
}
```

---

**EDIT:** From version [Yii 2.0.8](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/97/yii-2-0-8-is-released/) you can use this chained syntax as well:

```
$this->addColumn('contacts', 'email', $this->string(64)->after('id'));
```

Answer (score 15):

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn('contacts', 'email', $this->string(64)->after('id'));
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why - this way it will be easier for a newer user to learn from your answer.

Comment: Also, note from which version is the `after` method available. (From 2.0.8: http://www.yiiframework.com/news/97/yii-2-0-8-is-released/)

Answer (score 9):

You can use migration command for that as below :

```
php yii migrate/create add_email_column_to_contacts_table --fields="email:string(64):after('id')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the migration name is of the form `add_xxx_column_to_yyy_table` then the file content would contain `addColumn` and `dropColumn` statements necessary.

So you should run the following command to add column `email` to table `contacts`:

```
php yii migrate/create add_email_column_to_contacts_table --fields="email:string(64)"
```

Documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#add-column